# How to fix div height and image size in div?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am trying to do angular cdk drag and drop with 2 lists with bootstrap. First list has only one and main image, second list has other images with same size.

What I have (Very bad):

[image: What i have (Very bad)]

HTML:

```
 <div class="card mb-4" style="max-height: 20rem">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title mb-3"><strong>Media</strong></div>
                <div class="row" style="max-height: 100%" cdkDropListGroup>
                    <div class="col-8" style="height: 100%;">
                      <div
                        cdkDropList
                        [cdkDropListData]="images1"
                        class=""
                        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                        <div class="" *ngFor="let item of images1" cdkDrag><img [src]="item" alt=""></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="col-4 row" style="height: 100%; max-height: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; 
                    overflow-y: scroll;">
                      <div
                        cdkDropList
                        [cdkDropListData]="images2"
                        class=""
                        (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                        <div class="col-12 d-flex" *ngFor="let item of images2" cdkDrag><img [src]="item" alt=""></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I want:

[image: What i want]

Comment: Why not just use `height: 50%` on the 'other' images?

Comment: @Arjun not working. If i use "row" on wrapper div, can not change height.